# RDBMS to MongoDB using Talend 6.1.2 throwing error

Tags: mongodb, talend

I am trying to convert data from ORacle to MongoDB JSON format . But when trying to convert, I am getting following error when writing to JSON field. can anyone help.  I have attached the flow and the mapping

[image]

[image]

## Error message

```
tarting job ora2mongo at 03:14 17/08/2018.

[statistics] connecting to socket on port 4071
[statistics] connected
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Incorrect number of arguments for type Queue<E>; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <>
    Syntax error on token "null", delete this token
    Syntax error on token "null", delete this token
    Syntax error on token "null", delete this token
    queue cannot be resolved or is not a field
    queue cannot be resolved to a variable
    queue cannot be resolved or is not a field
    queue cannot be resolved to a variable
    Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete Assignment
    Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
    The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable
    Syntax error on token "null", invalid ClassType
    Syntax error, insert "new ClassType ( )" to complete Expression
    Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete Assignment
    Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
    Syntax error on token "null", invalid ClassType
    Syntax error, insert "new ClassType ( )" to complete Expression

    at rdbms_to_mongo.ora2mongo_0_1.ora2mongo.tOracleInput_1Process(ora2mongo.java:3156)
[statistics] disconnected
    at rdbms_to_mongo.ora2mongo_0_1.ora2mongo.tOracleConnection_1Process(ora2mongo.java:550)
    at rdbms_to_mongo.ora2mongo_0_1.ora2mongo.runJobInTOS(ora2mongo.java:5272)
    at rdbms_to_mongo.ora2mongo_0_1.ora2mongo.main(ora2mongo.java:5129)
Job ora2mongo ended at 03:14 17/08/2018. [exit code=0]
```

Comment: How can anybody help here without knowing what you do? Please [edit] your question and post your code as a [mcve]!

Comment: Why did you put tWriteJsonField (processor component) without output link?
You have an error warning on it, connect its output to tLogRow and show please its configuration)